# Try to use llvm LoopPass to find number of loops in program

Tags: llvm

I am trying to write a llvm pass program to count the number of loops within a program. Then I find LoopPass, which is explained in following link:

http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#the-looppass-class

Three functions are mentioned: doInitialization, runOnLoop, doFinalization.

I originally consider that "doInitialization" runs once at the start of program, "runOnLoop" runs for each time a loop is finished, and "doFinalization" runs at the end of program. I want to define a variable as counter, to be set to "0" in "doInitialization", count++ in "runOnLoop", and output result in "doFinalization".

Here is my code (partial):

```
virtual bool doInitialization(Loop * L, LPPassManager &LPM)
{
    errs() << (*(L->block_begin()))->getParent()->getName() << '\n';
    count = 0;
    length = 0;

    return false;
}

virtual bool runOnLoop(Loop * L, LPPassManager &LPM){

  count++;
  for(Loop::block_iterator b = L->block_begin(), e = L->block_end(); b != e; b++)
  {
    length++;
  }

  return false;
}

virtual bool doFinalization()
{
    errs() << "# of loops:              " << count << '\n';
    errs() << "average depth of loop:       " << (float)(length)/count << '\n';

    return false;
}
```

But from the result, "doInitialization" seems to work for number of times equal to number of loops in one function, "runOnLoop" works as expected, "doFinalization" seems to work at the end of a function. So I get two problems:

1. Why should "doInitialization" works multiple times?
2. If I want to get the total number of loops within a program (a program may have many functions, I do want "doFinalization" works only once for a program), what should I do?

Thanks to all relative answers,

Answer (score 1):

Why is `doInitialization` called multiple times?

Counting all loops within the program I would write a `ModulePass` and overwrite its `runOnModule()`. Module `M` you can access all functions *(I think the `begin` and `end` function should return appropriate iterators)*.

Then I can use `getAnalysis()` to get a `LoopInfo` object for the specified function. That object provides iterators to iterate over all top-level loops. If such a loop contains nested loops all nested loops of the "second level" can be retrieved by using `getSubLoops`. So for nested loops you would have to use that `getSubLoops` recursivly until no more subloops exist. Then I could increase some counter for each loop object. So it would look like this (I know that code is not compiling):

```
int loopcounter;
void handleLoop(Loop *L) {
  ++loopcounter;
  for (Loop *SL : L->getSubLoops()) {
    handleLoop(SL);
  }
}
virtual bool runOnModule(Module&M) {
  loopcounter = 0;
  for (auto &IT = M.begin, END = M.end(); IT != END; ++IT) {
    LoopInfo &LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfo>(*IT);
    for (LoopInfo::iterator LIT = LI.begin(), LEND = LI.end(); LIT != LEND; ++LIT) {
      handleLoop(*LIT);
    }
  }
  DEBUG(errs() << "Found " << loopcounter << " loops.\n");
}
```

To make the `getAnalysis` call work properly you will have to overwrite the `getAnalysisUsage()` and add a dependency to `LoopInfo` by calling `AU.addRequired<LoopInfo>()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because the loop pass is not initialized once for an entire compilation, it's initialized everytime you analyze a loop.
2. I'd add a debug statement to an existing loop pass that prints something unique, then use `grep -c` on the output of a compliation with `-debug-only=<pass_you_modified>`